# Do other countries create the equivalent of a TFR when US VIP's visit?

Tags: usa, tfr

In the US, there's a TFR everywhere a designated VIP (US president or vice president) is going to be. When (most?) foreign VIPs visit the US, I don't think there are TFRs in place for them (unless the location coincides with our VIPs).

Are there TFRs (or international equivalents) in other countries when the US VIPs are there?

Comment: yesterday (25-03-2014) when the president arrived in Brussels Airport airspace was cleared. http://www.deredactie.be/cm/vrtnieuws/buitenland/2.32602?eid=1.1919218 (dutch link),

Comment: I don't know. I was at Andrews AFB once pre-flighting when the King of Saudi Arabia on his 747 flew in and we were grounded. There's definitely some sort of restriction when foreign VIPs come in.

Comment: I imagine this has a lot to do with how much inconvenience the hosting country is willing to endure. (I would further posit that in many cases if the hosting country says "Screw you, we're not mucking up our airspace for your self-important behinds!" some foreign dignitaries would probably refuse to travel there, citing security concerns…)

Comment: The question title asks about the *US* creating a TFR for foreign VIPs, but the question body asks about *foreign countries* creating a TFR for US VIPs. Which one are you asking? Or both?

Comment: @Pondlife Sorry, I got confused and mixed up the title, I think it matches the question now.

Answer (score 4):

Absolutely!  The same airspace restrictions that are in the US are regulated by the FAA and ICAO.  The FAA (or the US) is a signatory to the ICAO standards, and as part of that governing body instituted the same rules worldwide. Those restrictions are also issued through the NOTAM system.

Incidentally, flying in the UK, we had restrictions on where we could fly depending on where the Queen was flying (if our missions coincided with her flights).  They even had a rather unflattering name for those flights in the pilot community.

[Here is an article that talks a little bit about th e roles and responsibilities of the Queen's pilots](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/queen-elizabeth-II/8694089/Queen-looking-for-80000-a-year-pilot.html).

[You can also check UK NOTAMS](http://notaminfo.com/node/5) (although i don't see any current ones fo rthe Queen at the moment).

Comment: I think the question was about US VIP's (e.g. the president and the Vice President) in international airspace like the UK. So, when Air Force One flies into the UK, will there be a UK NOTAM?

Comment: Doh! My bad!  I'll edit. And yes, NOTAMs are issued worldwide.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is. I remember last time when US president was in Prague, LKPR was closed for quarter or half an hour around his arrival.